# What does it mean when it says expected expression before UIAccelerationValue?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiaccelerometer

//this is the code that I've written. It says "expected expression before UIAccelerationValue" on the part where it says *accelerateValuesAll = UIAccelerationValue.

So, could anybody tell me what the problem is here? How do I fix it?

NSNumber *accelerateValuesALL = UIAccelerationValue.x + UIAccelerationValue.y + UIAccelerationValue.z / 3

Answer (score 1):

NSNumber is a class. You would therefore use it only via explicit messaging, such as:

```
[accelerateValuesALL floatValue];
```

Or by implicit Objective-C 2.0 dot notation:

```
accelerateValuesALL.floatValue;
```

You appear to want to use a primitive type — that is, one you can use the normal C operators on. So you probably want:

```
UIAccelerationValue accelerateValuesALL = ...;
```

Since UIAccelerationValue is a primitive type that UIKit defines for the purposes of passing around acceleration values. It'll just be an alternative name for a float or a double in practice.